# What is the use of the argument num in this code?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, mips, os161

The "*os161*" operating system contains the following code. Specifically, where the syscalls are defined:

```
...

#include <kern/syscall.h>
...

#define SYSCALL(sym, num) \
   .set noreorder       ; \
   .globl sym           ; \
   .type sym,@function      ; \
   .ent sym         ; \
sym:                ; \
   j __syscall                  ; \
   addiu v0, $0, SYS_##sym  ; \
   .end sym         ; \
   .set reorder

...

SYSCALL(fork, 0)
SYSCALL(vfork, 1)
SYSCALL(execv, 2)
SYSCALL(_exit, 3)
SYSCALL(waitpid, 4)
SYSCALL(getpid, 5)
...
```

At the bottom, each syscall gets a number. I can't seem to figure out what is the use of these numbers.

I'm not asking about the use of syscall numbers, I'm asking for the use of the argument `num` to the macro `SYSCALL`. I can't find where it's being used.

Even when the syscall number is moved to `v0`, the argument `num` is not used. Instead, it moves a constant defined in the file `kern/syscall.h`:

```
...

#define SYS_fork         0
#define SYS_vfork        1
#define SYS_execv        2
#define SYS__exit        3
#define SYS_waitpid      4
#define SYS_getpid       5
...
```

How can the argument `num` be useful somehow?

Comment: Pasting long copyright statement does not make it easier to understand the question. Consider editing and leaving only the relevant parts!

Comment: @dash-o Sure. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand it is not used at all. I suspect a remainder of a previous version where the `SYSCALL` macro was used to also define `SYS_sym`, instead of putting these definitions in `kern/syscall.h`. As it is now it still has at least one benefit: even if the `num` parameter is ignored by the macro, the code still shows the syscall number of each installed syscall. Anyway, did you try to remove it and run some tests?

Comment: @dash-o Not sure your recommendation about copyright statement is that wise. The copyright notice you wanted to be removed explicitly states that it should not be removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used for other tools to ease the maintenance of the source code.
The following is a quote from [Understanding System Calls](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ebianca/cscc69w13/assignments/UnderstandingSyscalls.html)

> syscalls.S: This file is created from syscalls-mips.S at compile time and is the actual file assembled into the C library. The actual names of the system calls are placed in this file using a script called callno-parse.sh that reads them from the kernel's header files. This avoids having to make a second list of the system calls. In a real system, typically each system call stub is placed in its own source file, to allow selectively linking them in. OS/161 puts them all together to simplify the makefiles. Adding new entries to callno.h automatically causes new user-level system call procedures to be defined when you re-build the user-level code. Each "SYSCALL(name,num)" macro statement in this file is expanded by the C pre-processor into a declaration of the appropriate system call function.

kern/syscall.h most likely is produce by one of those tools.